How to select all rows in Supabase?
I have a table named 'locations' and I am trying to fetch all records.
Here's a snippet of my code
const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('locations')
    .select(*)
    .order('country', { ascending: true })
    .order('state', { ascending: true })

I have over 25000 rows with all 50 US states, and I only get 3 of the States to return.
I even tried to increase the limit:
const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('locations')
    .select(*)
    .order('country', { ascending: true })
    .order('state', { ascending: true })
    .limit(25000)


That didn't work.

In Supabase's API settings, there's an option for configuring the max rows. As a precautionary measure it's set to 1000. These resolved the error.
